# Create custom boolean?

Tags: c#, syntax

How do I create a replica of the bool syntax and without using `true` and `false` I would use `Enabled` and `Disabled`? I would like it to be used like so...

```
sBool E = Enabled;
sBool f = Disabled;

if (e || f == Disabled)
{
    Do something...
}
```

Comment: [True, False, FileNotFound](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

Just make an enum as such

```
public enum sBool 
{
    Enabled,
    Disabled
}
```

Then you declare your code will look like this:

```
sBool E = sBool.Enabled;
sBool f = sBool.Disabled;

if (E  == sBool.Disabled || F == sBool.Disabled)
{
    //Do something...
}
```

**EDIT:** fixed the `if` syntax

Comment: This won't work. It requires an implicit conversion from int to bool.

Comment: Is there any way you would know on how to remove the sBool prefix? so it would just be "== Disabled" ?

Comment: Apart from the syntax in the `if` structure, I have no idea why this wouldn't work @xen-0. Daniel, I don't think there is a way, why would you want that anyway?

Answer (score 2):

It's a little cheat, but you can declare on two variables like this:

```
Boolean Enabled = true;
Boolean Disabled = false;
```

Now you can write in your code:

```
Boolean sBool = Enabled;
```

The disadvantage: Enabled and Disabled haven't special color..

Answer (score 1):

You could use an enum, like so:

```
enum Status 
{
    Enabled,
    Disabled
}

var e = Status.Enabled;
if (e == Status.Disabled) 
{
    // Do something
}
```

I'm not sure what your use case is but in terms of code readability/maintainability I'd say using an enum is the most simple solution and easiest for other developers to understand.

Comment: Is there any way you would know on how to remove the Status prefix? so it would just be "== Disabled" ?

Comment: You could always create your own class which overrides the equality operator. I'll put up an example for that. edit: Looks like someone has already done it.

Answer (score 1):

If sBool plays a *significant role* in your project, you may opt to implement a corrsponding full scale *struct* (not *enum*):

```
public struct sBool {
  private Boolean m_Value;

  public static readonly sBool Enabled = new sBool(true);
  public static readonly sBool Disabled = new sBool(false);

  ...

  private sBool(Boolean value) {
    m_Value = value;
  }

  ...

  public override bool Equals(object obj) {
    if (!(obj is sBool))
      return false;

    sBool other = (sBool) obj;

    return other.m_Value == m_Value;
  }

  public override int GetHashCode() {
    return m_Value ? 1 : 0;
  }

  ...

  public Boolean ToBoolean() {
    return m_Value;
  }

  public static implicit operator Boolean(sBool value) {
    return value.m_Value; 
  }  
}

....

sBool e = sBool.Enabled;
sBool f = sBool.Disabled;

if (e || f == sBool.Disabled) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Again I need to drop the sBool prefix if possible like so "`== Disabled`"

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a good way to do this.
You can exploit the fact that enums are really just ints with fancy names and use bitwise operators to emulate the logical operators.

So:

```
enum Status { Disabled = 0, Enabled = 1 }

Status a = Status.Disabled;
Status b = Status.Enabled;
if( (a | b) == Status.Enabled){
     //Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use a bool, but if you really want to encapsulate the logic in a separate class with the most readable syntax possible you could do something like this:

```
public sealed class Status: IEquatable<Status>
{
    public Status(bool isEnabled)
    {
        _isEnabled = isEnabled;
    }

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
    }

    public bool IsDisabled
    {
        get { return !_isEnabled; }
    }

    public bool Equals(Status other)
    {
        return other != null && this.IsEnabled == other.IsEnabled;
    }

    public static implicit operator bool(Status status)
    {
        return status.IsEnabled;
    }

    public static Status Enabled
    {
        get { return _enabled; }
    }

    public static Status Disabled
    {
        get { return _disabled; }
    }

    private readonly bool _isEnabled;

    private static readonly Status _enabled  = new Status(true);
    private static readonly Status _disabled = new Status(false);
}
```

Then for your sample code, do this kind of thing:

```
Status e = Status.Enabled;
Status f = Status.Disabled;

if (e || f.IsDisabled)
{
    // ...
}

// Alternatively:

if ( e.Equals(Status.Enabled) || f.Equals(Status.Disabled) )
{
    // ...
}
```